# How to use Implicit templates with a RIA services model

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

On the RIA server I have a model hierarchy however when the Silverlight client side model is generated the hierarchy is flattened.  In other words, on the client side all the types inherit from a common `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity` base class.

This hasn't been a problem until now.  The problem comes in trying to take advantage of Silverlight 5 implicit templates feature.  In this feature the selection of the 'DataTemplate' is based on the data type of the DataContext which now has all it's inheritance washed away.

Is there a common workaround to this?  At the moment the best that I can think is to create wrapper classes strictly on the Silverlight side, to serve as my selector.  I can then bind the ItemsSource to a collection of these wrapper classes, which should still connect me to the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

RIA Services does support inheritance, but it flattens everything down to what the server actually exposes. Try adding a query method in your DomainService that exposes the base type that you don't want flattened out.